# Right Drawer Layout out of margin

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I'm using DrawerLayout in my app. 
I test it in Samsung note 3 and samsung S4 everything is fine. But when it test to Samsung S3 the layout has messed up.
Please refer to below image

Test in Samsung Note 3 and Samsung S4 :
http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1514046988962

Test in Samsung S3 :
http://www.imagesup.net/?di=14140469921515

My xml layout code as following below :

```
 <include
    android:id="@+id/shopping_cart_slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    layout="@layout/shopping_cart_redesign"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

And this is layout that included :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_register_text" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shopping_cart_redesign_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey_register_text"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/info_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon" />

                <com.zukami.apps.dev.blynk.util.CustomListView
                    android:id="@+id/list_shopping_cart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/logo_image"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:divider="@color/grey_register_text"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
                </com.zukami.apps.dev.blynk.util.CustomListView>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/border"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/list_shopping_cart"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/grey_register_text" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/total_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/border"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/total_text_container"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/total_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="@string/total"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/merchandise_total"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="@string/merchandise_total"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/loyalty"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="@string/loyalty"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/total_number"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/total_points"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:textSize="15sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/border_two"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/total_layout"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/confirm_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/border_two"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/grey_shopping_cart_button"
                    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/confirm_order"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/space"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/confirm_button"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/receipt_border"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/info_container"
                android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
                android:src="@drawable/receipt_border" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/receipt_footer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/receipt_border"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLargeInverse"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Kindly advise what's wrong with this layout because I have set all width to match parent but still not working in all device.
Really appreciate for any kind help.

Comment: Not related but you should really cut down on the number of layouts used. For example you could remove the root relative layout and have the scroll view be the root layout.

Comment: @Spidy , thanks for your response. I have edit my xml layout as above but result still same. Kindly advise is there still any mistake that I did?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I cant see anything wrong right now.

One time I had a problem that anything on my code was wrong, but on devices running API 18+ the `android:gravity="center_vertical"` simple did not work, but I fix it just changing the value of `android:target="18"` to `android:target="16"`. I choose "16" because it was the version of my Android that was running without any problems.

I don't know if this is your case, but change the android target property at Android Manifest.xml, just give it a try (y)

Comment: thanks for your reply but still not working in my side.